# Excel macro to create and then fill a column with the same word/value?

Tags: excel

I need a macro that will create a column called "Store". Then, the macro should fill all active rows below with the word "admin".

Any ideas how to get this done?

Thanks a million for helping!

Comment: What is an "active" row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Macro recorder to get this done, search for macro record in the help. The exact location depends on your Office version

in 2007 follow this instruction http://www.fgcu.edu/support/office2007/Excel/Macros.asp

When you started recording you can open the source file, insert the column, name it and then copy down the values. then stop record

Open the Macro in the Editor using ALT+F11 to make it more general. Use Google "Macro VBA" to learn more about excel macros.

Good luck!

Comment: yopu should accept the answer, so that people help you in the future